# Jquery .map Click Event on specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Helllo,
i have a Array like this:

```
let Array1 = [
    {name:"try1", id:"id1", symbol:"symbol1"},
    {name:"try2", id:"id2", symbol:"symbol2"},
    {name:"try3", id:"id3", symbol:"symbol3"},
    {name:"try4", id:"id4", symbol:"symbol4"},
    {name:"try5", id:"id5", symbol:"symbol5"}
]
```

and i want to make each of them a button. that i can click on each one.
for this, i use .map Funnction ( im not sure this is the best option )

```
Array1.map(data => $(".check").html(`<a id="${data.id}" class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button">${data.id}</a>`))
```

until now i get 5 buttons. 1 button each object with the id of the button.

the problem start here: i trying to catch a Click Event on this buttons. i cant make it done..

I tried:

```
(`${data.id}`).click(e => console.log("click))
```

I would be happy for help or any other way with the same result. Thankss !!

Comment: `(``)` what is the selector you used?

Comment: ${data.id} . edited in post

Comment: Instead of adding a separate click event listener on all the buttons, add a click event listener on the parent element of all the buttons and using `Event.target`, you can check whether a button was clicked and also which button was clicked.

Comment: "_i use .map Funnction ( im not sure this is the best option )_". No, it isn't. You simply use it as a loop. In that case use `.forEach`. `.map()` is only useful if you assign its outcome to something. (`let arr2 = arr.map(...)`)

Comment: Would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if i have solved your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function with [event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for your dynamically added `buttons`.

Also you need use jQuery [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) function which will add all the button in the `.check` class. Using `.html` will replace the last one only shows the last button.

Run snippet below. `Clicks` are working on each one.

```js
let Array1 = [{
    name: "try1",
    id: "id1",
    symbol: "symbol1"
  },
  {
    name: "try2",
    id: "id2",
    symbol: "symbol2"
  },
  {
    name: "try3",
    id: "id3",
    symbol: "symbol3"
  },
  {
    name: "try4",
    id: "id4",
    symbol: "symbol4"
  },
  {
    name: "try5",
    id: "id5",
    symbol: "symbol5"
  }
]

   //Loop through the array1
Array1.forEach(function(data) {
  //Append Each button
  $(".check").append(`<a id="${data.id}" class="btn btn-info myBtn" href="#" role="button">${data.id}</a><br>`)

})
 
//Click function on buttons
$(document).on('click', '.myBtn', function() {
   //get the id
  let getId = $(this).attr('id')

  //do something

  //Console
  console.log(getId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a passive listener:

```js
let Array1 = [
    {name:"try1", id:"id1", symbol:"symbol1"},
    {name:"try2", id:"id2", symbol:"symbol2"},
    {name:"try3", id:"id3", symbol:"symbol3"},
    {name:"try4", id:"id4", symbol:"symbol4"},
    {name:"try5", id:"id5", symbol:"symbol5"}
]

Array1.map(data => $(".check").append(`<a id="${data.id}" class="btn btn-info new-btn" href="#" role="button">${data.id}</a><br>`))

$(document).on("click", ".new-btn", (e) => console.log(e.target.id))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Array1 = [{
    name: "try1",
    id: "id1",
    symbol: "symbol1"
  },
  {
    name: "try2",
    id: "id2",
    symbol: "symbol2"
  },
  {
    name: "try3",
    id: "id3",
    symbol: "symbol3"
  },
  {
    name: "try4",
    id: "id4",
    symbol: "symbol4"
  },
  {
    name: "try5",
    id: "id5",
    symbol: "symbol5"
  }
];

Array1.forEach(({
  id
}) => {
  $(".check").append(`<a id="${id}" class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button">${id}</a>`);
  $('#' + id).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#' + id).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check"></div>
```

Comment: using `forEach` will do the job why use `map` and `foreach` together. Less code is always better.

Comment: After realising others answers are better and using `forEach`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping after realising means?

Comment: Means you have seen answers above and changed your code as well.  Simple as. Anyways all good.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I realized wrong in my answer itself so updated it. No need to copy it.